# Apache VFS sftp- is getting multiple fileObjects creating multiple sessions or channels?

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, apache-commons-vfs

Consider the following code:

```
FileSystemManager fsManager = VFS.getManager();
FileObject sftpDir = fsManager.resolveFile("sftp://username:password@host/pub/downloads/");
FileObject child1 =  sftpDir.getChild("child1.data");
FileObject child2 =  sftpDir.getChild("child2.data");
InputStream s1 = child1.getContent().getInputStream();
InputStream s2 = child2.getContent().getInputStream();
```

On the Jsch underlying level, were two separated sessions created, or one session and two channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two/more channels in one session.

The `getInputStream` implementation calls `SftpFileSystem.getChannel()`, which creates new channel or reuses existing idle channel.

Comment: Obviously, two channels. I guess you meant **one session** and two channels